# PubNub message not sent when removing group channel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pubnub

We are trying to publish a message to multiple channels at once, using the following [scheme](https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000043826-can-i-publish-to-multiple-channels-at-once-).

Essentially, each client maintains a group channel, and whenever a server wants to send a message to multiple clients it does the following:

1. Create temporary channel (using a new GUID each time as a name).
2. Add temporary channel to each client's group channel.
3. Send the message to temporary channel.
4. Remove temporary channel.

It all worked fine when we were debugging, because we had breakpoints set all over the place.  But we noticed once we remove breakpoints, the message would no longer reach its destination.  We eventually narrowed the issue down to step #4 above (removing temporary channel).  When we commented that code out, and kept temporary channel, the messages would finally reach their destination.

The scheme recommended by PubNub above, specifically states the following:

> Once the publish succeeds (on success of the publish) you can then
>   remove the channel from every one of those channel groups.

We are using PubNub's REST api and RestSharp to issue request, and the above statement does not seem to hold true, unless we're doing something wrong.

Here's the code that sends the messages:

```
var request = new RestRequest("publish/{pub_key}/{sub_key}/0/{channel}/0", Method.POST); //No callback rigth now <TODO>

request.AddUrlSegment("pub_key", _pubNubPubKey);
request.AddUrlSegment("sub_key", _pubNubSubKey);
request.AddUrlSegment("channel", channel);
request.AddJsonBody(messageJson);
var response = await ExecuteAsync(request);
```

Only once that response returns true does the code removing the channels gets executed:

```
var request = new RestRequest("v1/channel-registration/sub-key/{sub_key}/channel-group/{groupChannelName}", Method.GET);

request.AddUrlSegment("sub_key", _pubNubSubKey);
request.AddUrlSegment("groupChannelName", groupChannelName);
request.AddParameter("remove", channelName);
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: There are some eventual consistency latencies with channel group persistence likely at the root here (on the add side, not remove, probably). I would ignore that old design pattern. Why not just create a channel that is unique to each end user/device and publish to all in a loop? This will involve the same number of transactions. And why not use PubNub C# SDK? Why do you use REST API?

Comment: @CraigConover Thanks. 1. We were under the impression that the number of transactions would be effectively halved when using group channels (since you're only publishing once, instead multiple times for each recipient).  2. We decided to use REST API, since are hosting the PubNub service inside ASP.NET Core environment and wanted a light-weight fire-and-forget method of publishing notifications, instead of having to worry about newing up and maintaining connection ourselves with each request.

Comment: 1) [Add/Remove to/from channel group are replication transactions](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/transaction-classification#replicated-stream-controller), same as a publish is. 2) PubNub C# SDK maintains TCP keepalive (or it is should be configurable) and if you keep the instance at proper scope, you don't have to create the instance with each publish, but your way works just fine, too. :)